# GKE - Quotas on Ingress objects

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, quota

It looks there is a quota enforced by GKE on the number of Ingress objects (max 100). I don't see this limit documented anywhere, has anyone seen it before and understands where it comes from ? The error message returned is:

Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "myweb.yaml": ingresses.networking.k8s.io "my-ingress" is forbidden: exceeded quota: gke-resource-quotas, requested: count/ingresses.networking.k8s.io=1, used: count/ingresses.networking.k8s.io=100, limited: count/ingresses.networking.k8s.io=100

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many nodes do your GKE cluster have?

Comment: 3 nodes - there is a documented limit of 110pods per node, but I've never heard of any quotas for Ingress objects. Does it ring any bell to you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/quotas#resource_quotas), Google automatically applies a set of resource quotas to clusters with ten nodes or fewer and to namespaces on those clusters. You can check the resources quotas for your cluster by running the following command:

```
kubectl get resourcequota gke-resource-quotas -o yaml
```

I created a new cluster with 3 nodes and here's the result of the above command on that cluster:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-01-07T16:12:00Z"
  name: gke-resource-quotas
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1300"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/resourcequotas/gke-resource-quotas
  uid: <redacted>
spec:
  hard:
    count/ingresses.extensions: "100"
    count/jobs.batch: 5k
    pods: "1500"
    services: "500"
status:
  hard:
    count/ingresses.extensions: "100"
    count/jobs.batch: 5k
    pods: "1500"
    services: "500"
  used:
    count/ingresses.extensions: "0"
    count/jobs.batch: "0"
    pods: "0"
    services: "1"
```

When I created a cluster with 11 nodes, this command returned `resourcequotas "gke-resource-quotas" not found` meaning that this quota is indeed applied to cluster with 10 nodes or less.